# How do we configure the loading of global Angular Material theme stylesheets for Storybook?

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, angular-material, storybook

How do we configure Angular Themes for Storybook such that the Storybook rendered components can load all the classes provided by the Angular theme?

There's a [Styling and CSS](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/styling-and-css) "Hint" in the storybook documentation, but no example at how to go about loading the compiled global Angular SASS style sheets.

Comment: Added an issue to Storybook for this: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/21694

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's really simple.  To import `styles.scss` just add this to `./storybook/preview.js`:

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!../src/styles.scss';
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is Nx specific but should be adaptable.

If you’re using a singular storybook-host

Example `libs/storybook-host/project.json`

```json
{
  "name": "storybook-host",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "projectType": "library",
  "sourceRoot": "libs/storybook-host/src",
  "prefix": "yourOrg",
  "targets": {
    "storybook": {
      "executor": "@storybook/angular:start-storybook",
      "options": {
        "port": 4400,
        "configDir": "libs/storybook-host/.storybook",
        "browserTarget": "storybook-host:build-storybook",
        "compodoc": false,
        "styles": [
          {
            "input": "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css"
          }
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "ci": {
          "quiet": true
        }
      }
    },
    "build-storybook": {
      "executor": "@storybook/angular:build-storybook",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputDir}"],
      "options": {
        "outputDir": "dist/storybook/storybook-host",
        "configDir": "libs/storybook-host/.storybook",
        "browserTarget": "storybook-host:build-storybook",
        "compodoc": false,
        "styles": [
          {
            "input": "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css"
          }
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "ci": {
          "quiet": true
        }
      }
    },
    "test-storybook": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "command": "test-storybook -c libs/storybook-host/.storybook --url=http://localhost:4400"
      }
    }
  },
  "tags": ["type:storybook"],
  "implicitDependencies": [
    // ui library names
  ]
}
```

With `preview.html`

```html
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```

---

A hazardous guess at what `angular.json` will look like (it's been awhile since I've messed around with these files).

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-project": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        // ...
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-project:build"
          }
        },
        // ...
        // starting from here
        "build-storybook": {
          "builder": "@storybook/angular:build-storybook",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/storybook"
            "configDir": ".storybook",
            "compodoc": false,
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css"
              }
            ]
          },
          // similar for storybook, test-storybook
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "my-project"
}
```

Comment: It's perfect!  Hopefully there's a way to shoehorn this into an Angular 15 project ...

Comment: Should be possible. In a standard `angular.json` the "executor" is just called "builder" and none of the above `@storybook/angular:start-storybook` etc. are Nx-specific. Would have to adapt the options as above. Simplest being `"storybook": { "builder": "@storybook/angular:build-storybook", "options": { "outputPath": "dist/storybook"  } }`

Comment: Hopefully.  I filed a feature request with Storybook and I'm hoping they will have some additional insight on how to do this.

Comment: It turned out to be really simple.  To import `styles.scss` globally just add this the import to `preview.js` like this: `import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!../src/styles.scss';`.  If you want to update your answer with this solution I'll accept and upvote.

Comment: It’s your answer, please post as self answer.